# How to print an image to its exact size in iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ipad-2, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am printing different images in my application. problem is printer always print the image in the whole page. if image size is very small printer print in the whole page and it looks very bad. i am using the following code for printing image:-

```
        NSData *dataFromPath = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 1.0);
    if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {

        printController.delegate = self;
        UIPrintFormatter *my=[[UIPrintFormatter alloc]init];
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = @"print image";
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;
        printController.printInfo = printInfo;
        printController.showsPageRange = YES;
        printController.printingItem = dataFromPath;
        [printController presentFromRect:_btn_ShareAction.frame inView:_btn_ShareAction.superview animated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
            }
        }];

    }
```

Comment: so i want a solution that allways print image according to it size and not allways take the whole page.

Comment: i tried to make the image smaller so that it print correctly but still same problem, anyone know about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `printingItem` you can use the `printPageRenderer` property and implement your own printing logic, which will enable you to print at the exact location and size as you wish.